# how to use ant design form initialValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-apollo

Which is right using antd Form initialValue?

I want to know that if antd form initialValue is using to set initial data or just to show value when the form doesn't have value.

```
const Component = ({ id }) => {
  const initialName = 'John'
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_NAME, { variables: { id } })
  if (data) { 
    initialName = data.name 
  }

  return (
  <Form.Item>
    {form.getFieldDecorator('name', { initialValue: initialName })(<Input />)}
   </Form.Item>
 )
}
```

```
const Component = ({ id }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_NAME, {
    variables: { id },
    onCompleted: res => { form.setFieldsValue({ name: res.data.name }) }
  })

  return (
  <Form.Item>
    {form.getFieldDecorator('name', { initialValue: 'John' })(<Input />)}
   </Form.Item>
 )
}
```

Comment: For anyone reaching this question while searching for dynamic `initialValues`: Check [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22372#issuecomment-602102164).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will set the value to what you assign initialValue to, so the first approach is right

you can check it here https://ant.design/components/form/#API

Answer (score 15):

You should wrap your form items with the Form component and add the initial value to the Form instead of the Form.Item.

```js
<Form
  initialValues={{ username:'default value' }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}>
  <Form.Item
    label="Username"
    name="username"
    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]}>
      <Input />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 10):

For me, setting the `initialValues` works if it an object that is already present when the form loads, let's sat it is "static". However, when that object is fetched async (using a `useEffect` hook), `initialValues` or even settings `initialValue` on the form's items, doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your questions as questions, not anwers!
Anyway, I think [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22372#issuecomment-602102164) answers your question. You should call `setFieldValues` each time the initial values change.

Answer (score 8):

Using "setFieldsValue" inside useEffect works amazing!

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.form.setFieldsValue({
        someFormField: formCalculatedValue,
    });        
}, [someDependencies]);
```

Comment: this saves the day.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the doc is clear. I made a mistake. Instead of `initialValue` I used `initialValues` (plural) in `getFieldDecorator`.

Also, make sure if the version you are using is Ant 3.X initiate their values in `getFieldDecorator` or if you're using version 4.X use `initialValues` as an attribute of Form.