# how can I initial value in the From of antd design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am creating a CRM website.
I need to edit my form, which needs to preload the data into the form.
I try to initial my data into the field.
But it shows object Object.  Can I know how can I solve this situation?
"

"
"

"
"

"
"

"
"

"
"

"

My code:

```
   <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish}>
      {/* {console.log(typeof timeSlotObj)}
      {console.log(timeSlotObj.timeSlots)} */}
      <Form.List name="timeSlots" initialValue={timeSlotObj.timeSlots}>
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map((field) => (
              <Space
                key={field.key}
                style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                align="baseline"
              >
                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  name="slotId"
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "slotId"]}
                  hidden
                ></Form.Item>

                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  //   name={[field.name, "venue"]}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "venue"]}
                  //   initialValue={timeSlotObj.timeSlots[field.fieldKey].venue}>
                  rules={[
                    { required: true, message: "「必須填寫地點/地區" },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="地點/地區" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  //   name={[field.name, "date"]}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "dateKey"]}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: "必須填寫時段" }]}
                >
                  <RangePicker
                    ranges={{
                      Today: [moment(), moment()],
                      "This Month": [
                        moment().startOf("month"),
                        moment().endOf("month"),
                      ],
                    }}
                    onChange={selectDate}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  //   name={[field.name, "price"]}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "price"]}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: "「必須填寫價錢" }]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="價錢" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  //   name={[field.name, "quota"]}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "quota"]}
                  rules={[
                    { required: true, message: "「必須填寫攤位數目" },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="攤位數目" />
                </Form.Item>
                <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
              </Space>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => add()}
                block
                icon={<PlusOutlined />}
              >
                新增場次
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          更新
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

My initial value input :

```
  {
"timeSlotsFrom": [
    {
        "timeSlots": [
            {
                "slotId": 0,
                "venue": "Zone A",
                "date": [
                    "2021-04-08T07:42:11.839Z",
                    "2021-04-17T07:42:11.839Z"
                ],
                "price": "31",
                "quota": 0
            },
            {
                "slotId": 1,
                "date": [
                    "2021-04-08T07:42:15.914Z",
                    "2021-04-16T07:42:15.914Z"
                ],
                "price": "21",
                "quota": "2",
                "venue": "Zone B"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

}

There is my exiting output :
[There is my exiting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nafYv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, object Object means you are trying to print out an object. Are you sure you are passing the right value?

Comment: I am passing this array :
 "timeSlots": [ {.....} , {......} ] 

But I want to print these: venue date price quota into the form, how can do?

Comment: Did you check this out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61861111/how-to-use-ant-design-form-initialvalue

Comment: Try {fields.map((field) => (console.log(field)))} to see what you are actually trying to print out

Comment: I checked it out, but it is not the same case as  I cannot read  attributes of an object in the array.

Comment: Actually, I know what it is printed. It prints objects in the array. But I would like to map attributes of objects in the array into the form fields